# React Apollo client prop refetchQueries after mutation

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I have been reading the Apollo documentation and I can't find any examples on how to refetch after a mutation with the `client` props that is being passed by `withApollo` HOC.

My component:

```
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { withApollo } from 'react-apollo';
...

const getPosts =  gql`
{
    posts {
    _id
    title
    description
    user {
        _id
    }
  }
}`;


const deletePost = gql`
    mutation deletePost($_id: String){
        deletePost(_id: $_id)
    }
`;

class PostList extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        match: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        history: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    };
    state = {posts: null};

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.client.query({
                query: getPosts,
            }).then(({ data }) => {
                this.setState({ posts: data.posts });
            });
    }

    deletePost = postId => {
        this.props.client
            .mutate({
                mutation: deletePost,
                variables: {
                    _id: postId
                },
            })
            .then(({ data }) => {

                alert('Post deleted!');
            });
    };


    render() {
        const {posts} = this.state;    
        if (!posts) {
            return <div>Loading....</div>
        }

        return (
            <div className="post">
                ...stuff...
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withApollo(PostList);
```

I want to refetch the posts each time one is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The `posts` data that you render is in your component state, but you only query posts in [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount). This method is called only when your component is first rendered.

```
class PostList extends React.Component {

    fetchPosts() {
        this.props.client.query({
                query: getPosts,
            }).then(({ data }) => {
                this.setState({ posts: data.posts });
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchPosts();
    }

    deletePost = postId => {
        this.props.client
            .mutate({
                mutation: deletePost,
                variables: {
                    _id: postId
                },
            })
            .then(({ data }) => {
                this.fetchPosts()
            });
    };


    render() {
        const {posts} = this.state;    
        if (!posts) {
            return <div>Loading....</div>
        }

        return (
            <div className="post">
                ...stuff...
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

In fact, you do not even need to have a local state, you can rely on Apollo client local cache and use the [Query](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html) component as well as the [Mutation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/mutations.html) component.